# R: function dispatch -- diff

Tags: r

I encountered this issue when working with diff on a xts object, and wonder how the generic function dispatch works in this case. Please see the sample code below.

```
> library(quantmod, quietly=T)
> x <- xts(data.frame(x=1:5), order.by=as.Date(1:5))
> y <- as.zoo(x)
> diff(x, lag=-1)
Error in diff.xts(x, lag = -1) : 
  'diff.xts' defined only for positive lag and differences arguments
> diff(y, lag=-1)
           x
1970-01-02 1
1970-01-03 1
1970-01-04 1
1970-01-05 1
```

The `diff` function does not work on `x` which is a `xts` object, yet works on `y` which is a `zoo` object. My question is which `diff` function is being used on `y`:

1. Both `diff.xts` and `diff.default` will fail on `y`;
2. Yet there is not a function named `diff.zoo`.

I must miss a point here. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `diff.zoo` is not exported, but it does exist. See `zoo:::diff.zoo` (of course you must have the `zoo` package installed).